# I want to move a file based on part of the name to a folder with that name

Tags: python, python-re, python-os

I have a directory with a large number of files that I want to move into folders based on part of the file name. My list of files looks like this:

```
001-020-012B-B.nc
001-022-151-A.nc
001-023-022-PY-T1.nc.nc
001-096-016B-A.nc
```

I want to move the files I have into separate folders based on the first part of the file name (`001-096-016B`, `001-023-022`, `001-022-151`). The first parts of the file name always have the same number of numbers and are always in 3 parts separated by an underscore `'-'`.

The folder names are named like this `\oe-xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\001-Disc-PED\020-Rotor-parts-1200`.

So for example, this file should be placed in the above folder, based on the folder name (the numbers):

```
001-020-012B-B.nc
```

File path divided into column to show where the above file has to be moved to:
`(001)-Disc-PED\(020)-Rotor-parts-1200`.

Therefore:

```
(001)-Disc-PED\(020)-Rotor-parts-1200 (001)-(020)-012B-B.nc
```

This is what I have tried from looking online but it does not work:
My thinking is I want to loop through the folders and look for matches.

```
import os
import glob
import itertools
import re

#Source file
sourcefile = r'C:\Users\cah\Desktop\000Turning'
destinationPath = r'C:\Users\cah\Desktop\08-CAM'

#Seperation
dirs = glob.glob('*-*')

#Every file with file extension .nc
files = glob.glob('*.nc')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sourcefile):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".nc"):

            first3Char = str(file[0:3])
            last3Char = str(file[4:7])

            for root in os.walk(destinationPath):

                first33CharsOfRoot = str(root[0:33])

                cleanRoot1 = str(root).replace("[", "")
                cleanRoot2 = str(cleanRoot1).replace("]", "")
                cleanRoot3 = str(cleanRoot2).replace(")", "")
                cleanRoot4 = str(cleanRoot3).replace("'", "")
                cleanRoot5 = str(cleanRoot4).replace(",", "")

                firstCharOfRoot = re.findall(r'(.{3})\s*$', str(cleanRoot5))

                print(firstCharOfRoot==first3Char)

                if(firstCharOfRoot == first3Char):
                    print("Hello")
                    for root in os.walk(destinationPath):
                        print(os.path.basename(root))

                     #   if(os.path)
```

I realized that I should not look for the last 3 chars in the path, because it is the first (001) etc. Numbers that I need to look for in the beginning to find the first path that I need to go to.

EDIT:

```
    import os
import glob
import itertools
import re

#Source file 
sourcefile = r'C:\Users\cah\Desktop\000Turning'
destinationPath = r'C:\Users\cah\Desktop\08-CAM'

#Seperation
dirs = glob.glob('*-*')

#Every file with file extension .nc
files = glob.glob('*.nc')



for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sourcefile):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".nc"):
            
            first3Char = str(file[0:3])
            last3Char = str(file[4:7])


            for root in os.walk(destinationPath):
                
                
            

                cleanRoot1 = str(root).replace("[", "")
                cleanRoot2 = str(cleanRoot1).replace("]", "")
                cleanRoot3 = str(cleanRoot2).replace(")", "")
                cleanRoot4 = str(cleanRoot3).replace("'", "")
                cleanRoot5 = str(cleanRoot4).replace(",", "")

                firstCharOfRoot = re.findall(r'^(?:[^\\]+\\\\){5}(\d+).*$', str(cleanRoot5))
                secondCharOfRoot = re.findall(r'^(?:[^\\]+\\\\){6}(\d+).*$', str(cleanRoot5))
                

                firstCharOfRootCleaned = ''.join(firstCharOfRoot)
                secondCharOfRoot = ''.join(secondCharOfRoot)


                cleanRoot6 = str(cleanRoot5).replace("(", "")

                if(firstCharOfRootCleaned == str(first3Char) & secondCharOfRoot == str(last3Char)):

                    print("BINGOf")
                  #  for root1 in os.walk(cleanRoot6):
```

Comment: Have you tried with [`split("-")`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/split.html) on your filenames ?

Comment: What should that help? I already "splitted" them and puled the numbers with regex and replace, isn't that the same result anyways?

Comment: You can then format the destination path, that would be the straightforward way to do it. I proposed an answer showing you the steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

There is an improved solution in the next section. But let's decompose the straightforward solution before.

First, get the complete list of subfolders.

```
all_folders_splitted = [os.path.split(f)\
    for f in glob.iglob(os.path.join(destinationPath, "**"), recursive=True)\
    if os.path.isdir(f)]
```

Then, use a function on each of your file to find its matching folder, or a new filepath if it doesn't exist. I include this function called `find_folder()` in the rest of the script:

```
import os
import glob
import shutil

sourcefile= r'C:\Users\cah\Desktop\000Turning'
destinationPath = r'C:\Users\cah\Desktop\08-CAM'

all_folders_splitted = [os.path.split(f)\
for f in glob.iglob(os.path.join(destinationPath , "**"), recursive=True)\
if os.path.isdir(f)]

# It will create and return a new directory if no directory matches
def find_folder(part1, part2):
    matching_folders1 = [folder for folder in all_folders_splitted\
                    if os.path.split(folder[0])[-1].startswith(part1)]
    matching_folder2 = None
    for matching_folder2 in matching_folders1:
        if matching_folder2[-1].startswith(part2):
            return os.path.join(*matching_folder2)

    # Whole new folder tree
    if matching_folder2 is None:
        dest = os.path.join(destinationPath, part1, part2)
        os.makedirs(dest)
        return dest

    # Inside the already existing folder part "1"
    dest = os.path.join(matching_folder2[0], part2)
    os.makedirs(dest)
    return dest

# All the files you want to move
files_gen = glob.iglob(os.path.join(source_path, "**", "*-*-*.nc"), recursive=True)

for file in files_gen:
    # Split the first two "-"
    basename = os.path.basename(file)
    splitted = basename.split("-", 2)

    # Format the destination folder.
    # Creates it if necessary
    destination_folder = find_folder(splitted[0], splitted[1])

    # Copying the file 
    shutil.copy2(file, os.path.join(destination_folder, basename))
```

## Improved solution

In case you have a large number of files, it could be detrimental to "split and match" every folder at each iteration.

We can store the folder, found given a pattern, in a dictionary. The dictionary will be updated if a new pattern is given, else it will return the previously found folder.

```
import os
import glob
import shutil

sourcefile= r'C:\Users\cah\Desktop\000Turning'
destinationPath = r'C:\Users\cah\Desktop\08-CAM'

# Global dictionary to store folder paths, relative to a pattern
found_pattern = dict()

all_folders_splitted = [os.path.split(f)\
for f in glob.iglob(os.path.join(destinationPath , "**"), recursive=True)\
if os.path.isdir(f)]


def find_folder(part1, part2):

    current_key = tuple([part1, part2])

    if current_key in pattern_match:
        # Already found previously. 
        # We just return the folder path, stored as the value.
        return pattern_match[current_key]

    matching_folders1 = [folder for folder in all_folders_splitted\
                    if os.path.split(folder[0])[-1].startswith(part1)]
    matching_folder2 = None

    for matching_folder2 in matching_folders1:
        if matching_folder2[-1].startswith(part2):
            dest = os.path.join(*matching_folder2)
            # Update the dictionary
            pattern_match[current_key] = dest
            return dest

    if matching_folder2 is None:
        dest = os.path.join(destinationPath, part1, part2)
    else:
        dest = os.path.join(matching_folder2[0], part2)
    
    # Update the dictionary
    pattern_match[current_key] = dest
    
    os.makedirs(dest, exist_ok = True)
    return dest

# All the files you want to move
files_gen = glob.iglob(os.path.join(source_path, "**", "*-*-*.nc"), recursive=True)

for file in files_gen:
    # Split the first two "-"
    basename = os.path.basename(file)
    splitted = basename.split("-", 2)

    # Format the destination folder.
    # Creates it if necessary
    destination_folder = find_folder(splitted[0], splitted[1])

    # Copying the file 
    shutil.copy2(file, os.path.join(destination_folder, basename))
```

This updated solution makes it more efficient (especially when many files should share the same folder) and you could also make use of the dictionary later, if you save it.

Comment: the path i used with DISC-PED was just an example of many paths, im sry i should have specified that better.. 

There are many different paths with different names n shuch, for example:

C:\\Users\\cah\\Desktop\\08-CAM\\002-Disc-ASME\\004-Main-assembly-2000

C:\\Users\\cah\\Desktop\\08-CAM\\002-Disc-ASME\\021-Rotor-parts-1500

C:\\Users\\cah\\Desktop\\08-CAM\\002-Disc-ASME\\061-End-plate-parts-1500

@Whole Brain

Comment: I understand. Then you also need a recursive call to `glob.glob` to yield any file matching the pattern in sub-directories. I updated the answer.

Comment: I dont understand why you typed dummy parts? What does that do??

Comment: It is was typo, from my own testing.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/15hdsgi this is what my folders looks like, it seems like your code creates new folders and call them disc-PED.. I want to put the files into the folder that they belong to

in the nested folders, that already exists:
https://prnt.sc/15hdwnw

Comment: I am confused. Your files are all in the same directory and you want to move them all in existing directories ? So you want to find which directory each file belongs to ?

Comment: No i have two directories :) One of the which contains the files names.. The file is name xxx-xxx-xxx.xxxxx

This first two number 001-020-xxxx.xxxx
should go to the folder which contains the same number. so forexample this should go to xxxx\\08-CAM\\001-Disc-PED\\020-Rotor-parts-1200:     this directory

Im moving files from a dir to another dir. Im posting my answer on what i have right now

Comment: I posted the code i have right now in my edit, do you understand what i want from my previous comment?

Comment: Ok I get it. Yes I understand now, thanks.

Comment: Alright nice, are you able to help me out ? :D

Comment: Of course ^_^ I'm on it. I have a (hopefully) one last question: the destination folders always match the pattern : "xxx folder1/xxx folder2" with the same number of x as between the `-` in your file names ? Nothing else like "someword xxx folder1 / ..." ?

Comment: Destination folders always look like this. here are some examples:

C:\Users\cah\Desktop\08-CAM\009-Batch-cooker-PED\006-16000-assembly

C:\Users\cah\Desktop\08-CAM\009-Batch-cooker-PED\032- Handwheel-Assembly

C:\Users\cah\Desktop\08-CAM\041-Raw-material-bin\007

C:\Users\cah\Desktop\08-CAM\041-Raw-material-bin\013-Ø500-4-Assembly

C:\Users\cah\Desktop\08-CAM\071-Lamella-pump\012-Coupling-cover-assy

C:\Users\cah\Desktop\08-CAM\071-Lamella-pump\038

Does this makes sense? :)

Comment: Yes, that's a Yes then ! That will ease the process.

Comment: Also, if the folder dont exist, it will also be allowed to create a folder for it, just with the numbers not any names :)

Comment: Do you need help with it? :D Is something not making sense? :D

Comment: It does. I proposed a new solution, using a specific function for your needs. Tell me if that works for you.

Comment: Getting this error: https://prnt.sc/15hjyfg

Not sure on how to proceed

Comment: I did a few edit (variable names were not consistent). Please make sure you use the current one.

Comment: I used the one you just posed, look at my screenshot, i have shown the whole code and the error message in visual studio :)

Comment: It seems you've put a `&` before python in your command prompt. Try removing it.

Comment: no i found the error the intepreter bugged :) 

Now i get this message tho:
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] En fil, som allerede findes, kan ikke oprettes: 'C:\\Users\\cah\\Desktop\\08-CAM\\001\\96'
PS C:\Users\cah> 

It seems like it handles the first 50-100 files finem but then runs into this problem:)

Comment: That makes sense. The folders created during the process are not added to the list `all_folders`. So it will try to create it again if the same non-existing pattern is found. You can simply set `exist_ok=True` in `makedirs`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you i will test it now! :)

Comment: https://prnt.sc/15hlj43

new problem:)

When the dir does not exist, it just creates a new root folder, as you can see in the screenshot.
It is supposed to just create a folder inside the already existing 001-Disc-PED Folder, and do the same for the others with different names if you know what i mean:)

Comment: Yes I understand, that's not a big deal, give me a few minutes.

Comment: I updated the answer. I just changed the function a bit, to match in a more convenient way. I also included the `makedirs` inside the `find_folder()` function.